# @DefaultValue return empty string

Tags: java, jax-rs

I get request like
http://localhost:8080?sortBy=&sortDir=&page=10

javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue understand

My controller looks like

```
public class MyController {
    public Response test(@BeanParam Pageable params){

    ...
    }
}

@Data
public class Pageable {

    @QueryParam("sortBy")
    @DefaultValue("1")
    private String sortBy;

    @QueryParam("sortDir")
    @DefaultValue("ASC")
    private String sortDir;

    private int page;
}
```

And under the hood you can find, that java  check if parameter == null it put my default value, but in my request I have "" - empty string.

How to workaround situation with DefaultValue?

Comment: what request are we talking about? It's hard to get an idea if you only give half the context

Comment: on the top of my question
`I get request like http://localhost:8080?sortBy=&sortDir=&page=10`

Comment: that's an url, not a request

Comment: Excuse me, if I wrong. How should I show request correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Can simply assign default value like below :

```
@Data
public class Pageable {

 @QueryParam("sortBy")
 private String sortBy = "1";

 @QueryParam("sortDir")
 private String sortDir = "ASC";

 private int page;
}
```

Comment: It is a good one

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not fit my situation, because it returns to front {"sortBy":1,  "sortDir": "ASC} always